# Does what I eat affect how fat I grow?

Tags: slither.io

I don't have any hard evidence of this, but I feel sometimes I grow in different ways, sometimes getting fatter faster, whilst sometimes growing longer and thinner. Is there anything that affects this (e.g., eating large orbs/shiny orbs vs normal orbs), or does all food make me grow in the same way?

Answer (score 3):

The food will, in the end, make you the same width, no matter which orb type you eat. However, you do gain more points eating the larger orbs than eating the smaller orbs.

- The smallest, most basic orbs each give you one point.
- Medium-sized orbs each supply the snake with two points. (these are the default medium-sized orbs that come from the field, not another player)
- The largest default orbs will give you 3 points
- Finally, user-generated orbs vary in points due to the size of the snake.

*comes from trial and error (to figure out how much each orb was worth)*

Comment: Some even give a half point!